# Why can a scala function name be used where a function value is expected, when it is not a function value itself?

Tags: scala, lambda, wildcard, implicit-conversion, eta-expansion

```
def f(x: Int): Boolean = (x >= 0 && x < 4)

List(1, 3, 5).map(f)  // List(true, true, false)
f                     // does not compile
```

Why can `f` be used where a function value is expected, even if it is not a function value itself?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening?

In places where a function type is expected, `f` is converted to an anonymous function `(x: Int) => f(x)`.

```
def f(x: Int): Boolean = (x >= 0 && x < 4)
// f                    // f itself is not a function value
f(_)                    // f(_) is an anonymous function
List(1, 3, 5).map(f)    // f is converted to f(_) in places where a function type is expected
List(1, 3, 5).map(f(_)) // equivalent to last line
```

Why is `f` not a function value in the first place?

- Because the parameterless function `f` was not defined. A <strike>curried</strike> (parameterless) function value would work:

```
val g = (x: Int) => (x >= 0 && x < 4)
g
```

Why is `f` accepted as a function value?

- `map` expects a function type and because <strike>curried and uncurried versions of `f`</strike> `f` and `g` both do the same, the automatic conversion makes sense.
- another advantage is that `map(f)` has a cleaner look than `map(f(_))`.
- a disadvantage of all the automatic and syntactic sugar stuff that is done for you, is that it can be confusing

Comment: Note that the process of turning a **method** into a **function** is called `eta-expansion`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the core of the question. Often, in my thinking I'm stuck for the same reasons: I don't know what the compiler does. I think it's time to look more closely into the topic of compilers if I want to get on the next level.

Comment: Being pedantic, that's not a *curried* function, it's just a function value rather than a method. A curried function is one that is the result of taking a function with multiple arguments and turning it into a set of nested HOF.

Comment: @colorblind _" I think it's time to look more closely into the topic of compilers if I want to get on the next level"_ I do not think so. You really do not need to known what the compiler does and how. You usually just need to know a few tricks / syntactic sugar / rules it has. For example in this case, just knowing the compiler will convert a method to a function it one is expected should be enough to continue with your learning.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I appreciate the opinion. I thought about it and saw that in IntelliJ I can desugarize scala code, which may help me in the situations when I don't see that there is some "trick" involved.

Comment: @colorblind You can also printout different compiler [phases](https://typelevel.org/scala/docs/phases.html), for example, `scala -Xprint:typer foo.scala`. You can do this even in real-time inside REPL `:settings -Xprint:typer`. Now right after entering some Scala source, it will printout the phase. You can even see the bytecode with `:javap -`. You can also inline it with `scala -Xprint:typer -e "for { i <- List(1,2,3) if i > 2 } yield { i.toString }"`

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm very interested in this!